# AES encrypt in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aes

can't get the same value from example

```
 string = "MerchantID=PG300000000055&TimeStamp=1489630207&Version=1.0&MerchantOrderNo=S_1489630207&Amt=30&ItemDesc=UnitTest"

 key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
 iv = "1234567890123456"
```

encrypt by AES CBC

this is my code

```
def encrypt 
  s = "MerchantID=PG300000000055&TimeStamp=1489630207&Version=1.0&MerchantOrderNo=S_1489630207&Amt=30&ItemDesc=UnitTest"
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
  cipher.iv  = "1234567890123456"
  encrypted = cipher.update(s) << cipher.final
end
```

the example get this

"89931dedfbc62460c637791dde28cfa465d13c5141dca0e7c5ab75bc66c9d459b6eeb4f0
71afed1bb41cfc9b25613ae39724e6e3fe7d9223a181c29e580257802b815cc09263032d
2c804446542a0915d0abc05f9d63072d4397b6e6a81cbd2bd3ac04965755d85c7038a3c
1838d031a20bd98173b6e57949a48003dffa5521a "

and i got this

"\xB3v\xE1\xF8\xBC\x9C&A\b=H\r\xF4\xF9>\x13+\x12\xE5\x975\x85m}9\xCF\xDEp\xC5b\x00s\xD1\x1A\xC9<\x94^H&\xB8\x84!\xC4\xB8\xAA\x16bB\rB\x1C\xEA\xA3\x9CA\xF4\x85\xA8a\xE5\xD2\xC5\xE7\xCE\xDD;|+\xE6]\xEDvV\xF4\xB2M\x96:\xEC\x18\"\xAC\xD0\xB9\x82\xCF\xD7\t \xD0a\xDD\xCF\x14^;u\xB2\n\x9DYP\xE7^*U\xF9Ko\x13\xEC\xB2\x9A<7\x04\xAEG\xD4\x82\xBE(\xDA4K\xD3\x18"

if encoded by hex got

"b376e1f8bc9c2641083d480df4f93e132b12e59735856d7d39cfde70c5620073d11ac93c945e4826b88421c4b8aa1662420d421ceaa39c41f485a861e5d2c5e7cedd3b7c2be65ded7656f4b24d963aec1822acd0b982cfd70920d061ddcf145e3b75b20a9d5950e75e2a55f94b6f13ecb29a3c3704ae47d482be28da344bd318308569170f07115d91d11a636de99dd4"

how can i do to get the same encrypted

thanks

Comment: Which example are you referring to?

Comment: Do you want the final output hex-encoded or what? Is the example the desired output?

Comment: final output hex, the example perhaps wrong